# Auto generate XSD from BPEL? or BPEL from XSD?

Tags: xsd, jdeveloper, bpel

So I am new to BPEL, and indeed my XML knowledge is limited (but growing fast as I do this project). I am creating a webservice in BPEL. Now the drag and drop is fine, but what about complex types? I can modify the .xsd file to have them, but do I then need to edit my .wsdl file and .bpel file to match or is there a way to auto generate this to reflect the changes in the .xsd file.

I am using Jdeveloper 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about how JDeveloper is dealing with this, but conceptually BPEL only reuses type definitions made in WSDL and/or XSDs that are imported into the BPEL definition. Thus, if you change data types in your schema definitions, the BPEL process with use them accordingly.

To be more concrete, the typical scenario is that you have defined your schema in XSD, import that into your WSDLs and use it to define messages based on your schema. In your BPEL process, you can reference the message types (defined in WSDL) or elements/complexTypes (defined in the XSD).